# HTML form post response on same page

Tags: html, http, post, liferay, portlet

I developed a very simple portlet for Liferay which contains a form to submit a couple of parameters to an external Webservice. My problem is that when I press submit I get redirected to the URL of that webservice.

Is there a way to suppress the redirection and show the webservice response in the same portlet that i made the call from?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of the form code your using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript (AJAX) for send data to the webservice and directly get the response without redirecting the user. Then with the data you received from javascript, you can display them on the page.

You can do this with [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and the function [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Hope, I've helped you :)

Comment: I have never used ajax or jquery before , is there any chance you could post an example of a simple post to a webservice being done using ajax and jquery?

Comment: If you already used javascript, it's not that hard. I'm advicing you to learn it, it will help you a lot !

`$.ajax({
  url: "http://domain.tld/webservice,
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
  }
}).done(function ( data ) {
  if( console && console.log ) {
    console.log("Sample of data:", data.slice(0, 100));
  }
});`